# write a program to add all the prime numbers from one to hundred

Tags: java

What is wrong in my code?

Expected **output=1060**

I checked with 1000 prime numbers sum. It will show correctly 
    output 3682913

```
public class PrimeNumber {

      public static void main(String args[]){

            int number = 2;
            int count = 0;
            long sum = 0;
            while(count <100){ 
                if(isPrimeNumber(number)){
                    sum += number;
                    count++;
                }
                number++;
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }

        private static boolean isPrimeNumber(int number){

            for(int i=2; i<=number/2; i++){
                if(number % i == 0){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you're finding the first 100 prime numbers, instead of the primes between 1 and 100.

Comment: You are finding the first 100 primes, Not primes from 1-100. Change the while to while (number < 100)

Comment: As a side note, you can stop your `for` loop at `i <= Math.sqrt(i)`, although you should calculate that once before entering the loop.

Comment: @bpgeck but when I tried to get know the sum of 1000 prime number it will give correct output?uh quite suprising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are counting the first 100 primes, not the primes found in the range 1 - 100. You can lose the count variable entirely here.

Your code can be simplifed as such, using a for loop instead to go from 2 to 100 (1 not included, of course)...

```
public class PrimeNumber {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int number = 2; number <= 100; number++) {
            if (isPrimeNumber(number)) {
                sum += number;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    private static boolean isPrimeNumber(int number){
        for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: when compare to for loop while loop is much faster

Comment: @Ramasamy Any evidence for that assertion? It will iterate through all the numbers regardless, whether it is a while or a for loop. And the requirement ensures that we HAVE TO go through each number from 2 to 100. And a for loop is designed for that purpose. If it could end earlier, then a while loop would be better, but it can't end earlier than the 100 mark.

Answer (score 5):

You are counting up to **100 primes** but not up to **100 numbers**.

So your while loop should run up to 100 numbers.

This should be your main method:

```
int number = 2;
      int count = 0;
      long sum = 0;
      while(number <= 100){ 
          if(isPrimeNumber(number)){
              sum += number;
              count++;
          }
          number++;
      }
      System.out.println(sum);
  }
```

This would give your output **1060**.

Comment: Didn't downvote but it looks like your answer was just what people already commented. Seems like you just copied them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below given code to find the sum of first prime numbers between 1 to 100. It will give you correct output.

```
public class PrimeNumber {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int number = 2;
        int sum = 0;
        while(number <= 100){ 
            if(isPrimeNumber(number)){
                sum += number;
            }
            number++;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    private static boolean isPrimeNumber(int number){
        int sqrt = (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(number));
        for(int i = 2; i <= sqrt; i++){
            if(number % i == 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: He is not looking for a sum of first 100 prime numbers but of the prime numbers which are less than 100. I did not downvote though.

Comment: But see your explanation: "find the sum of first 100 prime numbers"

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. Edited now.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Trial{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean flag = false;
        int max = 1000001;
        long[] a = new long[max];
        a[0] = 2;
        int i = 3,j=0;
        long sum = 2;
        int t = in.nextInt();
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
            long sum1 = 0;
            int n = in.nextInt();
            if(n>=i){
            while(i<=n){
                for(int y=0;a[y]<=Math.sqrt(i);y++){
                    if(a[y]==0){
                       break;
                    }
                    else if (i%a[y]==0){
                       flag = true;
                       break;
                    }
                }
                if(!flag){
                   a[++j]=i;
                   sum+=i;
                }
                flag =false;
                i+=2;
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
         }
         else{
            for(int y=0;a[y]<=n&&a[y]!=0;y++){
                sum1+=a[y];
            }
            System.out.println(sum1);
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

here i stored prime numbers in an array if there is any query for the numbers which are already present in the array first 'if' statement will handle it and simple the sum upto that no. will be printed.This will save a lot time to recalculate the prime numbers and find their sum.